# How to do this kind of windows movement in VIM?

Tags: vim

First I have three windows splited like this:

```
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
| A  | B  | C  |
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |
```

So, how can I change them into this way?

```
         |      |
   A     |      |
_________|  C   |
   B     |      |
         |      |
```

This happens when I want to use both TagList & NERDTree. Both of them open a new window on the left side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. go to A and `Ctrl-w K`

   now your window should look like

   ```
   |    A    |
   |---------|
   |  B |  C |
   ```
2. then go to C and `Ctrl-w L`